# $\partial {f} / \partial{x} = xy, \partial {f} / \partial{y} = x + y $, what is $f$

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\partial {f} / \partial{x} = xy, \partial {f} / \partial{y} = x + y $, what is $f$ ?

Since $$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = x
\neq
1=
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}
$$
we cannot use the usual trick.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't differentiability imply continuity? But for continuity don't we require that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$

Comment: @mrnovice for multivariable function, differentiable doesn't imply continuity

Comment: Why do you think such a function exists?  Clearly $f=\frac12x^2y+g(y)$ from the first equation.  But then $f_y=x^2+g'(y)=x+y$ is not possible.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for clearing that up, disregard my comment then

Comment: No, this holds because both first partial derivatives exist.  Nowhere did this involve equality of mixed partials.

Comment: @Masami: If you expressed $f$ that way, then, for each $y = y_0$, taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$ proves that $g(x,y_0) - h(x,y_0)$ is a constant function of $x$. Let $k(y_0)$ be that constant. Then $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 y + k(y)$. (technically, it only proves $g(x,y_0) - h(x,y_0)$ is a locally constant function of $x$, but since the domain is connected, locally constant means constant)

Comment: @MasamiNagasawa If $f(x,y)=\frac12x^2y +g(x,y)-h(x,y)$, then $f_x\ne xy$ unless $g_x-h_x=0$.  This means that $g-h$ cannot depend on $x$ and is therefore a function of $y$ only. What is it that you fail to see here?

Comment: @Dr.MV yes I got it now

Comment: Perhaps you should delete these comments then as it adds clutter to the posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixed second derivatives of $f$ are continuous, and therefore equal. [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Symmetry_of_second_derivatives&oldid=773515516#Schwarz.27s_theorem).

Since they are not equal, the premise (that such an $f$ exists) is false.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=\int\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\,\text{d} x=\frac12x^2y+h_1(y)$$
and
$$f(x,y)=\int\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\,\text{d}y=xy+\frac12y^2+h_2(x)$$
then there are no $h_1(y)$ and $h_2(x)$ such that $xy+\frac12y^2+h_2(x)=\frac12x^2y+h_1(y)$, so there is no function $f$.

Answer (score 0):

As many have already suggested, no such f can exist, as for all differentiable f we *must* have that $f_{x,y} = f_{y,x}$.